# Flip animation for multiple DIV's

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-plugins

I have a strange problem it seems to be a simple one but I am unable to find the solution.

I have 3 `divs` that are generated by the drupal->views and every `div` contains a button on the bottom and I need to flip the `div` on button click. Basically, if div #1 is currently displayed and button is pressed the second `div` is shown with flip effect and same with the third `div`.

Here is the arrangement:

`<div class="views-row views-row-1 views-row-odd views-row-first">
      <div id="careers_excerpt_88" class="careers_excerpt">
      <div id="careers_description_88" class="careers_description">
      <div id="careers_form_88" class="careers_form">
</div>`

And the content is within the above three `divs`.

Now the problem is that I can show and hide these `divs` but the flip is not working. I have tried many JavaScript plug-ins, some work for two `divs`.

I just need help on this issue (or perhaps suggest me some good plug-ins).

Comment: Can you add a JSFIDDLE link with your full code?
Only a div is not good enough.

Comment: @manu ,, i have added the JSFIDDLE link , with out animation .
http://jsfiddle.net/tB2LA/
can you suggest me a way to .

Answer (score 0):

Check out [this tutorial](http://desandro.github.io/3dtransforms/docs/card-flip.html).

No need of a JS lib.

Simply use CSS, and don't forget to properly set these properties on the right elements:   `transform-style`, `transition`, `perspective`, `backface-visibility` and `transform`.

Beware of the vendor prefixes!

And also of Internet Explorer. [You can find some hacks for it.][3]

Answer (score 0):

I do not know what exactly is your functionality/Intention of the flip divs you are looking for, but here is a plugin which can be moderated to achieve what you want.

Here is the: [Demo and Plugin](http://www.jquery-steps.com/Examples)

And [Github Link](https://github.com/rstaib/jquery-steps)

Hope this helps.